# Jim and Myself?

Tags: pronouns

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When is it correct to use “yourself” and “myself” (versus “you” and “me”)?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1176/when-is-it-correct-to-use-yourself-and-myself-versus-you-and-me)
>   [Doubt about the subject in this phrase: I, me, or myself?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4173/doubt-about-the-subject-in-this-phrase-i-me-or-myself)
>   [Use of “myself” in business-speak](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2269/use-of-myself-in-business-speak)

Does it make sense to say that?

For example: Jim and myself could not attend the party.

If not, how would I say it? Thanks.

Comment: *Myself* indicates something happening *to me*. You need a simple pronoun: "Jim and I could not attend the party." See also http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/85252/i-me-and-myself and its linked questions.

Answer (score 3):

It makes sense, but many would object to it on grounds of style. *Myself* is a reflexive pronoun. Reflexive pronouns have two main uses. One is to reflect the action expressed in the verb back onto the subject, as in, for example, *I’ve hurt myself*. The other use is to emphasise a particular noun or pronoun, as in *I did it myself*, where the speaker wants to remove any doubt that anyone else did it. Some speakers use reflexive pronouns in the way shown in your example, but *I* would serve just as well, or better.

Comment: I think this use is a hypercorrection by people who are confused by the formal preference for "I" over the colloquially preferred "me".

Comment: I’m generally dubious about hypercorrection. ‘The Cambridge Guide to English Usage’ suggests that people think using _myself_ avoids drawing attention to themselves, which it doesn’t.

Answer (score 1):

Pedants are always telling us that we shouldn't say things like [“My wife and myself just got back from Hawaii”](http://bottomlineenglish.com/learn-the-lingo/top-grammar-errors), but the reality is many people think ***I*** sounds too "formal", and ***me*** sounds too "casual", so they just use the form anyway.

I think this is one of those contexts where it's important to remember that "grammar" is essentially a [post factum](http://www.infoplease.com/dictionary/brewers/post-factum.html) attempt to *describe/codify* how people *actually use language*, rather than a set of prescriptive rules telling us what we can and can't say.

That's just my own opinion, of course. If you *do* use *"myself"* in such constructions, don't be surprised if some people think this shows that you're somewhat "illiterate".